# How to get a column YYYY as procces_year and MM AS process_month from a date with YYYYMMDD and YYYYMM format? in Netezza sql

Tags: date, netezza, digits, datepart, nzsql

I have some dates like 20190101 (YYYYMMDD) and 201901 (YYYYMM) in a column called `process_date` and I need two columns, a column called `process_year` with the year (YYYY) and `process_month` with the month (MM), when I use

```
date_part('year',process_date::numeric(8,0)) as process_year
```

the dates in format 201901 (YYYYMM) take the value '20' and same with

```
date_part('month',process_date::numeric(8,0)) as process_month
```

take the value '19' to the same format 201901 (YYYYMM)

Answer (score 0):

I found one method:

```
substr(process_date,1,4) as process_year
```

and

```
substr(process_date,5,2) as process_month
```

Thanks for your help.